# apache POI java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipFile

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I try to make word document using Apache POI 4.0.0, but i get error

> > Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> >     org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipFile     at
> >     org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.create(OPCPackage.java:365)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.newPackage(XWPFDocument.java:158)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.(XWPFDocument.java:149)
> >       at model.Model_dokumen.Cetak(Model_dokumen.java:32)     at
> >     view.Frame_surat.cetak_dan_simpanActionPerformed(Frame_surat.java:414)
> >       at view.Frame_surat.access$400(Frame_surat.java:23)     at
> >     view.Frame_surat$5.actionPerformed(Frame_surat.java:211)  at
> >     javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
> >       at
> >     javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
> >       at
> >     javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
> >       at
> >     javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
> >       at
> >     javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
> >       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)    at
> >     javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at
> >     java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)  at
> >     java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2238)  at
> >     java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)     at
> >     java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2296)     at
> >     java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
> >     java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4897)
> >       at
> >     java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
> >       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4475)
> >       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2282)    at
> >     java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)   at
> >     java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
> >     java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)    at
> >     java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
> >     java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
> >     java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
> >     java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> >     java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
> >       at
> >     java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
> >       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)   at
> >     java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)    at
> >     java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at 
> >     java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
> >       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)   at
> >     java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
> >       at
> >     java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
> >       at
> >     java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
> >       at
> >     java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> >       at
> >     java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
> >       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
> >     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> >     org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile     at
> >     java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
> >     sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)     at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 43 more
> >     Blockquote

i following tutorial from this site : [tutorials point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi_word/apache_poi_word_installation.htm) , and i had trying any solutions from blog, forum, etc. but nothing works for me.
This is my code :

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package model;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;
import view.Frame_surat;

/**
 *
 * @author nasution
 */
public class Model_dokumen {

    public void Cetak(Frame_surat fs) throws Exception {
        try {
            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
//            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();//blank document
            //membuat paragraf

             //membuat dokumen surat keluar
            try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("Surat_keluar.docx"))) {
                //membuat paragraf
                XWPFParagraph paragraf = document.createParagraph();
                XWPFRun run = paragraf.createRun();
                run.setText("ini adalah halaman dokumen yg baru saja dibuat menggunakan POI");
                document.write(outputStream);
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Surat keluar berhasil dibuat");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Model_dokumen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Model_dokumen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: [poi-ooxml » 4.0.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/4.0.0) needs [commons-compress » 1.18](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-compress/1.18)

Comment: thanks, it's solved, i need common-compress

Comment: The hint given in the answer is not bad. But if I was told already from the exception that `org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile` was not found, then I would search using keywords `org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile jar`.

Comment: thank you, next time I will be more careful.

Comment: BOOM for Axel! Solved it for me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try searching for the class name then jar download you might find the specified jar files. "ex: XWPF jar files download." and download the classes of XWPF as jar files i got this problem before and I solved it like this but for me it was pdfBox.
PS: Try searching for jar files for "org.apache.poi.xwpf" you will get more results.

Comment: what  name the class that i must search ?

Comment: it's solved, i miss file common-compress.. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8):

For poi-4.1.0 I had to add these to the classpath:
    dom4j-1.6.jar
    xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar
    commons-collections4-4.3.jar
    commons-compress-1.18.jar
Only then did this work for Excel.xlsx File:

```
ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
```

Comment: I also needed to add commons-math.

Comment: With POI 5.0.0 (poi-5.0.0.jar) a lot of extra libraries are needed to do `Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(myFile)` (currently latest versions): commons-collections4-4.4.jar, commons-compress-1.20.jar, log4j-api-2.14.1.jar, log4j-core-2.14.1.jar, poi-ooxml-5.0.0.jar, poi-ooxml-lite-5.0.0.jar (you can also use the "full" one instead), xmlbeans-5.0.0.jar.

Answer (score 4):

For maven users, you can easily deduct from the package name that this is missing an apache commons-compress lib

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-compress

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-compress -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
    <version>1.20</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Got this for Android with AGP 7.0, with the following error:

> - What went wrong:
>   Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
>   `>` Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
>   `>` Could not create task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
>   `>` 'void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.(java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel)'

The root reason was that I hadn't installed the right build-tools' version.

So `sdkmanager 'build-tools;<buildToolsVersion>'` fixed the problem for me (where `buildToolsVersion` its the version you use in your build.gradle(s), 30.0.3 in my case)

Comment: Having this problem with Jenkins build after upgrading to AGP 7.0 and Java 11. May I ask when you state `<buildToolsDeclaredForYourProject>` do you mean you have it explicitly set in your build.gradle?

Comment: yes that is, I update the answer detailing this a little more