# Getting "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" for Testng Dataprovider with Excel

Tags: selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, testng-dataprovider

I am not able to get past the error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"

Tried:
1- Cleaning the project
2- Updating testng xml
3- Verified the package/class structure

Nothing seems to work:

Note: I am not using Maven and all jar files are latest (Testng, Apache, Selenium)

**Test Class code :**

```
@DataProvider(name ="calldata")
public Object[][] getData() {

    ExcelUtility util = new ExcelUtility("excel path");

    int rows = util.getRowCount(0);

    Object data [][] = new Object[rows] [6];

    for(int i=1; i<rows; i++)
    {
        data[i][0]=util.getData(0, i, 0);
        data[i][1]=util.getData(0, i, 1);
        data[i][1]=util.getData(0, i, 2);
        data[i][1]=util.getData(0, i, 3);
        data[i][1]=util.getData(0, i, 4);
        data[i][1]=util.getData(0, i, 5);
    }

    return data;
}

@Test(dataProvider ="calldata")
 public void AddaDependent(String url, String client, String eliggrp, String empnumber, String firstname, String SSN) 
    {
```

**Excel Utility code:**

package AllExcel;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelUtility {

```
XSSFWorkbook wb;
XSSFSheet sheet1;

public ExcelUtility(String excelPath)
{
    try
    {
        File src = new File(excelPath);

        FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(src);
        wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }
}

public String getData(int sheetNumber, int row, int column)
{
    sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    String data = sheet1.getRow(row).getCell(column).getStringCellValue();

    return data;
}

public int getRowCount(int sheetIndex)
{
    int row = wb.getSheetAt(sheetIndex).getLastRowNum();

    row = row+1;

    return row;
}
```

}

**Error:**

[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
[Utils] [ERROR] [Error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipFile
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:298)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:307)
    at AllExcel.ExcelUtility.<init>(ExcelUtility.java:22)
    at AutFramework.AddDependent.getData(AddDependent.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52381075/apache-poi-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-compress-archivers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically as per Axel's link, I copied "common compress jar" and the mentioned error went away, now I am getting another error and that needs to be handled in another question. closing this one for now

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are not using Maven, you can download the jar from here.
Add it to your class path and it should work:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.2

Reason being, Apache has removed the Interface ListValuedMap from commons-Collections4-4.0.

Comment: I already have the jar "commons-collections4-4.2.jar" added in build path, did you mean anything else to do ?

Comment: I added common compress jar and now I am getting the following error:


[Utils] [ERROR] [Error] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.typeMismatch(XSSFCell.java:1075)
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getRichStringCellValue(XSSFCell.java:396)
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getStringCellValue(XSSFCell.java:348)
 at AllExcel.ExcelUtility.getData(ExcelUtility.java:35)
 at AutFramework.AddDependent.getData(AddDependent.java:47)

Comment: you are calling getStringCellValue() on a numeric cell - that's why you get the exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell` - there are lots of examples of how to read poi cells properly - you need to use cell.getCellType() and depending on its type, call the getStringCellValue or getNumericCellValue or getBooleanCellValue etc

Comment: That error is pretty straightforward. You are reading a number from your excel but you attempting to assign the value read as a STRING instead of INTEGER, DECIMAL, LONG..

Answer (score 0):

Download the apache compress jars and add to library , I tried this and it worked fine.