# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipArchiveOutputStream

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to create docx file in Java using Apache POI.
Here is my code..

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;

public class DocGen {



    private static void createDocFile(String fileName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());

            XWPFDocument doc1 = new XWPFDocument();
            XWPFParagraph tempParagraph = doc1.createParagraph();
            XWPFRun tempRun = tempParagraph.createRun();

            tempRun.setText("-----Demo Paragraph-----");
            tempRun.setFontSize(12);
            doc1.write(fos);
            fos.close();
            doc1.close();
            System.out.println("-----------File Created At---------"+file.getAbsolutePath());


        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("-----Exception------"+e);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        createDocFile("/home/yashpatel/Documents/Doc1.docx");
        createDocFile("/home/yashpatel/Documents/Doc1.doc");
    }

}
```

Following are the jar files I have added..
[image]

I am getting the following error..

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipArchiveOutputStream  at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.create(OPCPackage.java:365)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.newPackage(XWPFDocument.java:158)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.(XWPFDocument.java:149)
>     at DocGen.createDocFile(DocGen.java:17)     at
>   DocGen.main(DocGen.java:37) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveOutputStream  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 5 more

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52381075/apache-poi-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-compress-archivers?rq=1