# I am Trying Data Driven Framework with Selenium. Where i have a sample program to get url from excel sheet and make browser open

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, data-driven-tests

[image]I am Trying Data Driven Framework with Selenium. Where i have a sample program to get url from excel sheet and make browser open. But all i am getting is URl= Null error. I have attached my code and error screenshot. What am i doing wrong. And Error I am getting is "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile"enter image description here

Error log:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipFile at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:298) at org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37) at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:307at com.excel.Excellib.main(Excellib.java:20) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFileat java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: Please add a full stack trace with error you see. It's not very clear where do you see URI = null;

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipFile
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:298)
 at org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:307at com.excel.Excellib.main(Excellib.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFileat java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipFile

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error log provided. Here's a topic that describes a similar issue:

[apache POI java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52381075/apache-poi-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-compress-archivers)

You need to add library: 
Apache Commons Compress » 1.18
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-compress/1.18