# Reading Excel by Apache POI and Java web application but showing error as "java.io.IOException: org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipFile"

Tags: java, servlets, apache-poi

In java web application i need to read the excel file's cell. i used apachi poi here. but it shows error as follows

### java.io.IOException: org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipFile

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;


public class importservlet extends HttpServlet { 

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();        
    try{

      File file=new File("E:\\Book1.xlsx");
      Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
      Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
      out.println(sheet.getRow(1).getCell(1).getCellType());
      wb.close();
      }
    catch(Exception e){
        out.println(e);
     }
    
     }

     }
```

i used following jar files

- poi-4.1.0
- poi-ooxml-4.1.0
- poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.0
- xmlbeans-3.1.0
- commons-collections 4.4.3

Comment: Please add full stack trace.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52381075/apache-poi-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-compress-archivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing `commons-compress` jar library

[commons-compress](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/download_compress.cgi)